# Python Issue Joining Binary Like Ojbects

Tags: python, binary

I have a few binary objects

```
binary_size = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

binary_length = b'\x00\x00\x00'
```

When I try to join them I get this:

```
binary_size.join(binary_length)
*** TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, int found
```

Previously, before converting them to binary they were ints, but if they are prefaced with `b` I don't understand why they wouldn't be considered binary.

Not sure if this is related:
https://bugs.python.org/issue24892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` is used like this (demonstrated with strings):

```
'<join_string>'.join(['str1', 'str2', 'str3'])
# 'str1<join_string>str2<join_string>str3'
```

You can join with an empty string:

```
''.join(['str1', 'str2', 'str3'])
# 'str1str2str3'
```

You have to call join on the bytes object that will join your bytes objects. It should be empty, so `b''` (Note the `b` as without it, you would get an empty `str` and would get an error trying to concatenate it with bytes):

```
binary_size = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'

binary_length = b'\xff\xff\xff'
joined = b''.join([binary_size, binary_length])

print(joined)
# b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff'
```

Note that you could do that simply with `+`:

```
print(binary_size + binary_length)
# b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff'
```

---

In your original code `binary_size.join(binary_length)`, you use `binary_size` as the string to join with, and the iterable of objects to join that you pass is `binary_length`. It is a bytes object, so iterating on it gives integers, which can't be concatenated with `binary_size`